# Synchronize or link open windows?

Tags: hyperlink, synchronize

So I was wondering if there was a way to synchronize or link open windows.  For example, if you have two word documents open side by side, if you scroll up on one it will scroll up on the other.  I thought this would be easy to figure out, but I'm having a hard time with it.  Is it even possible?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the feeling, having seen a little bit of how the input messages are handled from the mouse, that this isn't going to be something that is built in to Office, for example.

I think you could probably do it by programming a small script, but I don't believe there will be an option to toggle this functionality.